# How can I check if Shift+Enter is pressed on a textarea

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, dom-events

I want to submit the form if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed and stop the event if <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. The callback for this has `Ext.EventObject` parameter which does not provide any way to check if shiftkey is pressed.

it has two methods `.hasModifier` and `.isSpecialKey`. Both returns `boolean`. There is no way to find if shiftkey is pressed. how do I trace it?

This is my textarea component:

```
{
    region : 'center',
    margins : '5 0 0 0',
    xtype : 'textarea',
    name : 'chatmessage',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    listeners: {
        keydown: function(textfield, evt, eOpts){
            console.log(evt.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `evt.shiftKey`. Its undefined.

Comment: Looks like I'm late to the party, but I tested the evt.shiftKey property in 4.1.0 and it worked fine. Do you know if it's a bug in your version of Ext JS?

Comment: @EricCook I am using 4.0.6. According to manual `evt.shiftKey` should be set. It might be a bug or I am missing something. I am not sure about it.

Comment: BTW, I dont want to upgrade ExtJS as it changes quite drastically on each new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with little trick with keydown and keyup events a flag.

```
listeners : {
    keydown : function(tf, e, opt) {
        if (e.getKey() == e.SHIFT) {
            this.shiftKeyPressed = true; // a flag
            return;
        }
        if (e.getKey() != e.ENTER && (this.shiftKeyPressed == undefined || (this.shiftKeyPressed == false))) {
            // Submit form
            e.stopEvent();
        }
    },
    keyup : function(tf, e, eOpts) {
        if (e.getKey() == e.SHIFT) {
            this.shiftKeyPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a keymap?

Comment: Yes. I have used the keymap. I dont want to use it as it loads another 11K `.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a keymap ( http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap ) on your textarea? Can't test the code here but should be something like this:

```
var textArea= Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
    region : 'center',
    margins : '5 0 0 0',
    xtype : 'textarea',
    name : 'chatmessage',
    enableKeyEvents: true
});

var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
    target: textArea,
    binding: [{
        key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
        fn: function(){ alert('Enter pressed!'); }
    }, {
        key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
        shift:true,
        fn: function(){ alert('Shift+ENTER pressed!'); }
    }]
});
```

Comment: You'll likely want to hold a reference to the `KeyMap` object so you can call `destroy` on it when the parent component is destroyed.