# extjs Keydown for Tab back key press(Shift + Tab)

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have grid column key down event function I want to catch back Tab key press event

```
mycol.editor.addLissiner('keydown',keydownfunc(), this);

keydownfunc : function(txtField, e) {
 var key = e.getKey();

 if(key == Ext.EventObject.TAB){
  alert('tab);
 }
 if(key == TAB+SHIFT){
  alert('backtab');
 }

}
```

I can catch Tab key press using `key ==  Ext.EventObject.TAB` but i can't catch back tab press key event. Please help tell what i do for catch back tab(shift+tab) event

Answer (score 0):

Try checking 'Ext.EventObject.shiftKey' inside TAB key handler to determine shift key is pressed or not...

Comment: this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118944/extjs4-how-can-i-check-if-shiftenter-is-pressed-on-a-textarea` link has a solution but i need to check both keyup and keydown events. is there any singe event for shift+tab?

Answer (score 0):

you can observe :

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/sDFfY/"
```

this will surely help you.

Comment: this not extjs3 and this not mention SHIFT key press event